# PostgreSQL Question ! Port problem :( (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: postgresql

My cmd is looking for port 5432. Initially, it was set as 5433 in installation so I had to change it from *postgresql.conf*. But then I could not use pgAdmin because it is looking for port 5433 how do I make one of them look for the same port?

Comment: Port 5433 is usually the default for a second, different version of Postgres installed on the same machine. Take care when modifying all of your conf files and ensure you're editing for whichever version you intend to use. I'd suggest setting up the version you primarily want to use 5432. If you don't need the other version uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb question... But in case someone else has the same situation, the answer is to **right-click** on your server in ***pgAdmin***, click properties and then change the desired port!